# Cocos2d-x runAction Error

Tags: c++, action, cocos2d-x

Okay, so I want my cat sprite to move up and down onClick of two (UP and DOWN) buttons.
I'm a beginner in cocos2d-x. 
So, in mygame.h i have a global declaration of the sprite cat:

cocos2d::Sprite *cat;

In one function i create a new scene and add a cat in it.

```
    cat = Sprite::create("cat.png");
cat->setScale(0.2);
cat->setPosition(0, 190);//(Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin().x + 50,       Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize().height / 2);
layer->addChild(cat);
playscene->addChild(cat);
```

In another function(button callback) i have this code:

```
    void HelloWorld::down(Object* pSender){
CCActionInterval* down = CCMoveBy::create(1.0f, Point(0.0, -20.0));
cat->runAction(down);
}
```

And everything's ok untill i press the up or down button.
It throws an error on the cat->runAction(down); line.
When i exemine the variable cat, it looks like I cant get to the position parameters. Its a memory read error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing Cocos2D-X 2.x API's with Cocos2D-X 3.0 ones.  I'm taking a stab in the dark guess and saying it looks like you're trying to use 3.0.  You will need to change the following line:

`CCActionInterval* down = CCMoveBy::create(1.0f, Point(0.0, -20.0));`

To:

`ActionInterval* down = MoveBy::create(1.0f, Point(0.0, -20.0));`

Answer (score 1):

In cocos2dx 3.0
you can write direct in runaction for any sprite.

spriteName->runAction(Sequence::create(MoveBy::create(1.0f,Point(398,565)),NULL));

Comment: Please add some explanation. Explain why your code should work.